# Nested graph navigation with multi module android?

Tags: android, module, navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

My application has 3 modules

- app
- authentication
- home

app module has both other modules added in gradle

app module has main graph which contains nested graph from authentication and home module

I have login fragment in authentication module and I want to navigate to home fragment which resides in home module

Below are my graphs

Main graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment2">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/splashFragment2"
    android:name="splash.SplashFragment"
    android:label="fragment_splash"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_open_login"
        app:destination="@id/staging_authentication_nav_graph"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/staging_nav_graph"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
</fragment>

<include app:graph="@navigation/staging_authentication_nav_graph" />
<include app:graph="@navigation/staging_home_nav_graph" />
</navigation>
```

Authentication module graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_authentication_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/loginFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.ocatave.featureauthentication.LoginFragment"
    android:label="login_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/login_fragment">
</fragment>
</navigation>
```

This is the home graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/staging_home_nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="home_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" />

</navigation>
```

How can I navigate to homeFragment from loginfragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it with the help deeplink

in navigation graph

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.octave.home.HomeFragment"
    android:label="HomeFragment" >
    <deepLink app:uri="octave://home"/>
</fragment>
```

And the navigation code

```
findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse("octave://home"))
```